# Splitting elements in a list of list which is a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of list of string. I want to split the first element.

```
li = ["['ABC', 'DEF']",
      "['GHI', 'JKL']",
      "['MNO', ' ']",
      "['PQR', 'STU']"]
```

I want to get 'ABC' as my output.

Here is my code snippet:

```
print(li[0][0])
```

I'm getting '['. I know the reason. I tried to convert it in list as list(li). But all in vein. Can anybody help please.

Answer (score 8):

Evaluate the strings in your list to convert it to a list of lists:

```
import ast
li = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in li]
```

then you can proceed as required:

```
print(li[0][0])

'ABC'
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get "ABC"

```
eval(li[0])[0]
```

Comment: eval can be unsafe, I would recommend to use `ast.literal_eval`

Answer (score 1):

Use `json.loads`

```
import json

li = ["['ABC', 'DEF']",
      "['GHI', 'JKL']",
      "['MNO', ' ']",
      "['PQR', 'STU']"]
li = [json.loads(x.replace("'", "\"")) for x in li]
print(li[0][0])
```

output

```
ABC
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can do that:

```
li = [['ABC', 'DEF'],
      ['GHI', 'JKL'],
      ['MNO', ' '],
      ['PQR', 'STU']]
print(li[0][0])
```

Comment: Buddy that's what i'm asking how to convert to this list

Comment: see if you are saying that
 li = ["['ABC', 'DEF']",
      "['GHI', 'JKL']",
      "['MNO', ' ']",
      "['PQR', 'STU']"] this is a list of list then its wrong its just a list.

further a list of list would be this one
 li = [['ABC', 'DEF'],
      ['GHI', 'JKL'],
      ['MNO', ' '],
      ['PQR', 'STU']
Because when you put "" that makes the inside list as a string.

Comment: Just remove the "['Abc' , 'DEF']" (double quotes ) and make it ['ABC' ,  'DEF']

Comment: Wow great answer bro @sam2611